# Prevent apt-get from running

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I need to disable `apt-get` temporarily to get a specific "mode" of my Ubuntu-Workstation, where multiple users are working and nobody should be able to install any packages.

First idea was to open the lock-file under `/var/lib/dpkg`, to simulate an active run of apt-get, but I got there no success. Code I tried: `tail -f /dev/null > <lockfile> &`

Second idea was to disable access to apt-get via `chmod 0 /usr/bin/apt-get`. This works, but I think this is more than just dirty.

What else should I try?

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. 1) I think there is a specific ubuntu-portal at StackExchange. 2) The users should not be in the sudo(ers-file and group). This should actually be the default, did you try?

Comment: Quick hack: `function apt-get() { }` (or similar; I can't remember the exact syntax offhand)

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's best practice not to give the `wheel` role to those users. In that case, they can't use the `sudo` command, which is necessary to run `apt-get install`.